# Facebook share: Share from mobile website to app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I built a Facebook share dialogue on my website, which gets about 77% of its traffic from mobile devices. I am logging how many people click the button and how many of them actually share content. After some days it turns out, that the button is being clicked hundreds of times, but literally no one continues to actually share anything. The problem is: they get prompted to log into Facebook in their browser.

Is there any way to use an active FB-app login for sharing from a mobile website? And are there any differences between iOS and Android?

Comment: No there is not. If there was Facebook Login would do that automatically. How do you know if people share something or not?

Comment: When calling the share dialouge, FB.ui offers a callback function with a response that indicates, whether the share was done or not.